# "java.lang.NullPointerException" error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bluej

I'm getting an error "java.lang.NullPointerException" and BlueJ cannot seem to tell me what the error means. Below is the code in which the error is appearing:

```
public int getJobsWaiting()
{
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (count < jobList.size())
    {
        Job temp = jobList.get(i);

        if(jobList.get(count).isCompleted() != true)
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Something is `null`. You get a `NullPointerException` when you try to call a method or access a member variable of something that is `null`. In which line does the exception happen?

Comment: It is a standard Java error indicating that an object is `null` (i.e. nothing) and yet is trying to be dereferenced (with a `.`). Does it tell you the exact line on which the error occurs?

Comment: Have you initialized jobList?

What line is the error on?

Comment: the error is appearing on the "while (count < jobList.size())" line

Comment: (This is off topic, and unrelated to the problem you're experiencing). You probably shouldn't be comparing a boolean result to `true`  The expression `if (something != true)` can be more clearly written as `if (!something)`

Answer (score 2):

either `jobList` or `jobList.get(count)` is `null`. And if you try to invoke a method on `null` (in your case: `size()` or `isCompleted()`), you get exactly that, a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `isCompleted()` may also be `null` (if it's a `Boolean`)

Comment: @MarounMaroun, it can, actually. `if (test() != true)` will throw NPE in the cases when `test()` returns `null`, but not a boxed `boolean`. :)

Comment: @kocko Thanks for that :) I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it is less code and only jobList can be null

```
int count = 0;
for (Job tmpJob : jobList) {
  if (!tmpJob.isCompleted())
  count++;
}

return count;
```

Comment: still getting the "java.lang.NullPointerException” error after using that code

Comment: then your jobList is null... it would be useful to see where you instanciate the jobList or maybe the class with the getJobsWaiting() method

Answer (score 0):

Your code is difficult to understand. Variable temp is never used?

With this, if a job is completed, count+1 is not executed and the while is never ended?

```
if(jobList.get(count).isCompleted() != true)
{
   count = count + 1;
}
```

Check if this can help:

```
public int getJobsWaiting(List<Job> jobList) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < jobList.size(); i++) {
        Job temp = jobList.get(i);
        if (temp != null && !temp.isCompleted()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```